# Q: Limit with odd function

Tags: calculus, limits

If $f$ is an odd function, show using the 2-sided limits definitions that $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x) = L$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to 0-} f(x) = -L$.

Comment: What did you try doing?

Comment: Actually nothing, Im searching through the definitions trying to understand how im gonna prove it. In my understanding I will say that $\lim_{x\to 0-} f(x) = L$ and prove it wrong so it has to be $\lim_{x\to 0-} f(x) = -L$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f$ is odd iff $-f(-x) = f(x) \iff f(-x) = -f(x)$.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x) = L \iff -\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)  = -L \iff$$

$$\iff \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} -f(x)  = -L \iff \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(-x)  = -L$$

Using the fact that $f$ is odd to swap $-f(x)$ for $f(-x)$.
Now consider a change of variables $y = -x$. Then $x \rightarrow 0^+ \iff y \rightarrow 0^-$:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(-x)  = -L \iff \lim_{y \rightarrow 0^-} f(y)  = -L$$

And you have the required demonstration. In particular, $f$ is only continuous at the point $a$ if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} f(x)$ which, at $a = 0$, implies $L = -L \iff L = 0$.